# How to Plot an Equation, based on another plot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, parametric-functions

I've been struggling with this problem That I have an equation with two variables. One of them has a defined interval. Like this:
`T == ((k*v + g)/(k*g)) (1 - E^(-k*T))`(v and g are just constants)
and k is all real numbers between (0,0.08). Mathematica certainly can't solve "T" for me because I have an interval for the other variable (which is k). The only way is to solve this equation by using a plot. And here is the results. Let me know if I did it right:

`Plot[T /. NSolve[T == (k*v + g)/(k*g) (1 - E^(-k*T)), T, Reals], {k,0, 0.08}, PlotRange -> Full]`

[image: Plotting T]

Here Comes my actual problem. I have another equation based on T (that I've solved by plotting it) and k (with the same interval). Now I want to solve THAT equation. Here it is:
`Y = T/(1 - E^(-k*T))`

And it seems like Mathematica can't solve Y for me because T is a function (not just an answer) and k is an interval. So the only way is to Plot Y based on T and k. I have no idea how to do that. Here is another screenshot:

[image: Plotting Y based on T and k]

PLEASE HELP ME BECAUSE I'M IN A HURRY!!!

Comment: Please post all  of the code, not the picture.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is correct the syntax errors in the expression for `y1.`  Remove he brackets.  Also, what is `T'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

v = 600 Sin[60 Degree];

g = 98/10;

T[k_?NumericQ] := t /. 
   NSolve[{t == (k*v + g)/(k*g) (1 - E^(-k*t)), t > 0}, t, Reals];

Format[y1] = Subscript[y, 1];

y1[k_?NumericQ] := T[k]/(1 - E^(-k*T[k]))

Plot[{y1[k], T[k]}, {k, 0, 0.08},
 AxesLabel -> {Style[k, 12, Bold], None},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {0.6, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can `Reduce` the expression of `T`.

```
v = 600 Sin[60 Degree];
g = 98/10;
Reduce[T == ((k*v + g)/(k*g)) (1 - E^(-k*T))];
result=Simplify[%, T > 0]
```

When we substitute to `T/(1 - E^(-k*T))` ,we can get a simple result!

```
T/(1 - E^(-k*T)) /. 
  T -> (1500 Sqrt[3])/49 + 1/k + 
    ProductLog[C[1], 
     E^(-1 - (1500 Sqrt[3] k)/49) (-1 - (1500 Sqrt[3] k)/49)]/
    k // FullSimplify
```

> `(1500 Sqrt[3])/49 + 1/k`

```
Plot[(1500 Sqrt[3])/49 + 1/k,{k,0,10}]
```

[image]